# React JS is not working after it is hosted on IIS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, asp.net-core, react-redux

Issue: I've used the visual studio template to create react js application with asp.net core and redux. I have added a soap based web service as a connected service and calling it through the controllers. In my local machine (when i ran it through the visual studio solution), it is working fine. But when i host it on the IIS, it is providing me the metadata from service. React client is working fine, but the code that it should return from the controllers is not working.

This is what I'm getting from the payload:
[Here is the screenshot of the payload](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3C4vR.png)

Can someone please help me resolve this issue?

Here is the complete payload from redux :

Here is the complete payload I'm receiving (from redux):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
<base href="/ClientApp/build/"/>
<link rel="manifest" href="/ClientApp/build/manifest.json">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/ClientApp/build/favicon.ico">
<title>My application title name</title>
<link href="/ClientApp/build/static/css/2.e3c13add.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/ClientApp/build/static/css/main.18472c62.chunk.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="root" style="min-width:500px">
</div>
<script>!function(p){function e(e){for(var r,t,n=e[0],o=e[1],u=e[2],i=0,l=[];i<n.length;i++)t=n[i],Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(a,t)&&a[t]&&l.push(a[t][0]),a[t]=0;for(r in o)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(o,r)&&(p[r]=o[r]);for(s&&s(e);l.length;)l.shift()();return c.push.apply(c,u||[]),f()}function f(){for(var e,r=0;r<c.length;r++){for(var t=c[r],n=!0,o=1;o<t.length;o++){var u=t[o];0!==a[u]&&(n=!1)}n&&(c.splice(r--,1),e=i(i.s=t[0]))}return e}var t={},a={1:0},c=[];function i(e){if(t[e])return t[e].exports;var r=t[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return p[e].call(r.exports,r,r.exports,i),r.l=!0,r.exports}i.m=p,i.c=t,i.d=function(e,r,t){i.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:t})},i.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},i.t=function(r,e){if(1&e&&(r=i(r)),8&e)return r;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof r&&r&&r.__esModule)return r;var t=Object.create(null);if(i.r(t),Object.defineProperty(t,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:r}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof r)for(var n in r)i.d(t,n,function(e){return r[e]}.bind(null,n));return t},i.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return i.d(r,"a",r),r},i.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},i.p="/ClientApp/build/";var r=this.webpackJsonpnibrs=this.webpackJsonpnibrs||[],n=r.push.bind(r);r.push=e,r=r.slice();for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)e(r[o]);var s=n;f()}([])</script>
<script src="/ClientApp/build/static/js/2.c61b596a.chunk.js">
</script>
<script src="/ClientApp/build/static/js/main.7c65033f.chunk.js">
</script>
</body>
```

I found the reason to be - while calling the controllers, it is prefixing the controller methods with clientapp/build like this [http://localhost:8082/clientapp/build/api/login/istwofactorenabled].
This will give me a blank page. Instead, it should point to [http://localhost:8082/api/login/istwofactorenabled].

Now, I'm not sure how to make it access the controllers this way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I’m guessing it’s an unhandled internal server error. It has nothing to do with React.

Comment: please post the entire payload not only a part of it

Comment: Hi @beniutek, I've updated the payload. Can you please help me on this? I'm thinking the way i hosted might have something to do with it. I followed the steps from this link :https://www.roundthecode.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-web-hosting/how-to-publish-an-asp-net-core-react-spa-to-iis